# Search Functionality Within PhoneGap App

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a relatively simple app using PhoneGap that is designed to be a field guide.  Basically there will be buttons for different sections of the field guide.  Tapping on one of these buttons will transition the user to another page with the content.

However, I would like to implement search functionality if possible.  For example, the user could input a query and the app will return which "pages" that query appears on.  I'm not really sure what the best way to go about implementing this would be, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The only type of search function I've used thus far with PhoneGap is using a filter search to search on a set of list elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lots of .html files with your conten, a good option is to use [Zoom search engine](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/index.html).
You have to execute a program and it will scan your .html files and index keywords.
You will have to style yourself the "search results" page, because the default isn't mobile friendly